# The problem of ksdensity plot in Matlab

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, matlab, density-function

I want to verify that random numbers generated by `exprnd` match the exponential distribution. I used Matlab's `ksdensity` function – here's the code:

```
R = exprnd(10,1000,1);
[f,xi]=ksdensity(R);

x = 0.01:0.01:60; 
y = 0.1.*exp(-x./10); 
plot(xi,f,x,y); 
legend('exprnd','exp')
```

But the resulting plot shows that they do not match.[image: Matlab plot]

I checked and no random number is below zero, however the plot of `ksdensity` shows some points below zero that have probability. Why is that?

Comment: ksdensity is just smoothing out the (discrete) distribution that you started with through convolution with a Gaussian kernel. There is no real guarantee that the resulting pdf really matches the sampling that you did. A simpler test for validity would be to check that $e^{-\lambda X}$ is uniformly distributed, which I think should be possible using the 'box' kernel.

Answer (score 3):

By default [`ksdensity`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html) assumes that the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of the distribution is unbounded, i.e., a two-sided distribution. You can specify positive support via the [`'Support'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html#input_argument_namevalue_support) parameter:

```
[f,xi] = ksdensity(R,'Support','positive');
```